# Is There Dreamweaver Spry Alternatives?

Tags: dreamweaver

I am currently trying to find an alternative to the Spry Validation Confirm that Dreamweaver CS6 used to have. I upgraded to CC recently and I want to find an alternative that works similarly to Spry Validation Confirm function.

Thank You In Advance

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form  validation [www.jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)